# perl : HTML::Mason - Print a perl hash inside HTML tags in a tabular format

Tags: html, perl, email, mason

I am trying to send a html email (report) about the values in a hash. But I couldnt print the hash values in a table format. I am using [`HTML::Mason`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason) to execute my perl commands (looping through a hash) and printing it in the end of report. But my perl code is not getting executed.

```
use HTML::Entities;
use Mail::Sendmail;
use MIME::Lite;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use Time::localtime;
use HTML::Mason;

my $ti = localtime;
my ( $day, $month, $year ) = ( $ti->mday, $ti->fullmonth, $ti->year );

# DEFINE A HASH
%coins = ( "Quarter" => 25, "Dime" => 10, "Nickel" => 5 );

$html = <<END_HTML;
   Please direct any questions to <a href="mailto:abc@mydomain.com">MyEmailID</a><br><br>

  <table border='1'>
   <th>Keys</th><th>Values</th>
% while (($key, $value) = each(%coins)){       
   <TR>     
   <TD><% $key %></TD>      
   <TD><% $value %></TD>      
   </TR>       
% }
  </table>;

END_HTML

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    from    => 'abc@mydomain.com',
    To      => 'def@mydomain.com',
    Subject => 'Report',
    Type    => 'multipart/related'
);
$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => qq{
        <body>
        <html>$html</html>
        </body>
    },
);

MIME::Lite->send( 'smtp', 'xxxs.xxxx.xxxxx.com' );
$msg->send;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only wanting to generate a table, you could do this easily without using HTML::Mason:

```
use HTML::Entities;
use Mail::Sendmail;
use MIME::Lite;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use Time::localtime;

my $ti = localtime;
my ( $day, $month, $year ) = ( $ti->mday, $ti->fullmonth, $ti->year );

# DEFINE A HASH
my %coins = ( "Quarter" => 25, "Dime" => 10, "Nickel" => 5 );

my $html = '<table border="1">
<thead><th>Keys</th><th>Values</th></thead>
<tbody>';

while ( my($key, $value) = each(%coins)) {
    $html .= "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
}
$html .= "</tbody></table>";

my $greeting = 'Please direct any questions to <a href="mailto:abc@mydomain.com">MyEmailID</a><br><br>';
my $outtro = '<br><br>See yas later, alligator!';

$html = $greeting . $html . $outtro;

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    from    => 'abc@mydomain.com',
    To      => 'def@mydomain.com',
    Subject => 'Report',
    Type    => 'multipart/related'
);
$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => qq{
        <body>
        <html>$html</html>
        </body>
    },
);

MIME::Lite->send( 'smtp', 'xxxs.xxxx.xxxxx.com' );
$msg->send;
```

Unless you need a lot of complexity in your email, it is probably not worth using HTML::Mason for this purpose. If you're going to use HTML::Mason for an email, you'll need to set up your script to call it -  [see the pod for details](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason::Admin#Using-Mason-from-a-Standalone-Script). You can't just embed Mason commands in a string, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
# DEFINE A HASH
my %coins = ( "Quarter" => 25,
              "Dime" => 10,
              "Nickel" => 5, );

for my $no (keys %coins) {
    print qq(
    <table>
        <tr><td> $no </td></tr>
        <tr><td> $coins{$no} </td></tr>
    </table>
    );
}
```

Comment: I can print like this . But how can I attach the result (the table)to the existing html text, which I am sending in an email?

Comment: I think you have to rethink your process a bit. You did not mention earlier that you are sending it via email, so a little bit of clarification would be nice, as to what exactly are you trying to do. If I have understood you properly, one method might be: Generate a HTML page and save it temporarily, and send a copy of that file as a attachment with the email.

Comment: The 1st line in my question says clearly that i am trying to send an email. Anyways thanks for your attempt. But I need it as email body and not as an attachment.